# Reference javascript files to use visual studio 2010 intellisense 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-2010

I have a website with very heavy (long javascript > 100KB + JQuery). So, for making the javascript re-useable, I want to separate the logic in different javascript files.

So, I want to make an aggregated javascript file

[image]

Please tell me how (I even want to use the VS2010 intellisense in my main JS file about the functions of the other JS files.)

Comment: I think its ok to have the `js & jquery` somewhere aroud 100KB because `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`(latest jquery version) itself is like 90KB. If you want to compress your `js` files, use the `javascript compressor` tools which are freely available on net.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Javascript Intellisense tends to be extremely unreliable as some updates broke it some updates fixed it, and there are a lot of extensions around it, breaking each other.

Still there is a `/// <reference>` element for cases like this.

See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx) and add line:

```
/// <reference path="otherscript.js" />
```

at the top of your script file.

Try to test it with the jQuery vsdoc and your other script files.

Also installing MVC4 installed some dependency or whatever that more-or-less fixed javascript intellisense for me.

Comment: Didn´t know of the `///<reference...` tag but it seems useful, +1 :)

Comment: Also note that if you use it as the first line of <script> tag, it will give intellisense for that script block.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend Resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your Javascript files and use **[SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher)** to concatinate and compress/minify them all into one single file to reduce the file size and the number of requests.

I don´t know of any solution that allows you to work in both the concatinated file as well as each separated file ...and I don´t understand why anyone would want to.

IMO, Visual Studio has a quite poor intellisense for Javascript.