# Intellisense Jquery

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

I know it probably a really easy question to answer but I trying to get Intellisense Jquery working on Visual Studios 2010 over the whole project. I can get it working in one document easy. I've tried placing

```
 @if (false) { <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> }
```

in my layout page but again only works in this document. Does this mean i will have to copy this into every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use a dynamic generator for html files, yes you'll have to place it in the header of every page you need to add it to unfortunately. You should be changing you links too if you're going live.

```
 @if (false) { <script src="/../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> }
```

I just added a "/" before your src, so that browsers can find your files easier.

Answer (score 1):

if you can put this line on every page its good
alternative to this you can use `///reference` tag look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030906/reference-javascript-files-to-use-visual-studio-2010-intellisense)

the `///reference` tag also works inside other javascript files